# How is XOR helping find the unique value?

Tags: java, arrays, xor

I have a problem to writhe a function that finds the unique value from an array, i could not solve the problem but i asked someone to help, he provided the solution by using XOR(^), but could not explain for me to understand it. I know that XOR has the following table:

```
1 ^ 0 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0
0 ^ 0 = 0
0 ^ 1 = 1
```

So, if the values are different XOR returns 1 or a non negative value in case of other numbers but I still don't get how this is helping me to solve this.
Can someone please explain how the code below is working and how is it finding the unique value?

```java
int xor = 0;
int index = 0;
    
while(index < arr.length) {
    xor = arr[index] ^ xor;
    index++;
}
    
return xor;
```

Comment: `x ^ x = 0` (anything xor'd with itself is zero). `a ^ b ^ c = (a ^ b) ^ c = a ^ (b ^ c)` (xor is associative). `a ^ b = b ^ a` (xor is commutative). Does that help?

Comment: This algorithm may not work in every possible situation. Are there any assumptions we should be aware of ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the elements of the array can be grouped as pairs of equal numbers, XORing each pair of numbers will result in `0`.
The order in which the elements are XORed doesn't matter.

For example, if the array is 4,5,4,5

```
xor = arr[0] ^ xor; // 0..0100 ^ 0..0000 = 0..0100
xor = arr[1] ^ xor; // 0..0101 ^ 0..0100 = 0..0001
xor = arr[2] ^ xor; // 0..0100 ^ 0..0001 = 0..0101
xor = arr[3] ^ xor; // 0..0101 ^ 0..0101 = 0..0000 = 0
```

If, on the other hand, all the elements of the array but one can be paired, after XORing all of them, only that one un-paired element will remain.

For example, if the array is 4,5,6,4,5

```
xor = arr[0] ^ xor; // 0..0100 ^ 0..0000 = 0..0100
xor = arr[1] ^ xor; // 0..0101 ^ 0..0100 = 0..0001
xor = arr[2] ^ xor; // 0..0110 ^ 0..0001 = 0..0111
xor = arr[3] ^ xor; // 0..0100 ^ 0..0111 = 0..0011
xor = arr[4] ^ xor; // 0..0101 ^ 0..0011 = 0..0110 = 6
```

Comment: What happens if a number occurs 3, 5, 7, or any odd number of times in the array ?

Comment: @nquincampoix each pair of numbers cancels each other. So if the array is 2,2,3,2,3 - you'll get 2. If there is more than one element with odd number of occurrences, this loop won't find them. For example - if the array is 2,2,3,2,3,3 - it will return 2^3 == 1

Comment: But in the case `[2, 2, 3, 2, 3]`, 2 is not a unique value.

Comment: @nquincampoix yes, that logic finds the unique number only for arrays where 1 element appears once and all the rest appear an even number of times.

Answer (score 1):

This work only when you have one unique value and even number of duplicate values.

Consider the following test case:
`7 ^ 3 ^ 5 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 3 ^ 4`
This can be rearranged as `7 ^ (3 ^ 3) ^ (4 ^ 4) ^ (5 ^ 5)`

- xor is commutative: A ^ B = B ^ A

  xor is associative: (A ^ B) ^ C = A ^ (B ^ C)

  xoring with zero does nothing: A ^ 0 = A

  xoring something twice removes it: A ^ A = 0

Applying this rules on above test case gives
`7 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ 0` then `7 ^ 0` i.e `7`

[Refer this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-c-cpp/) for more info about XOR